# Using Url.Content with semi-relative URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am storing the location of images in my database in an MVC application...but i am only storing part of the location. For example:

```
/headers/image1.jpg
/headers/image2.jpg
```

The images are actually stored in the following folder:

```
~/content/images/headers/image1.jpg
~/content/images/headers/image1.jpg
```

In my view, I want to do something like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images") + Model.ImageUrl" />
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @Dismissile, I suggest storing the full path in the database, if you ever need to change the folder name it's all in one place, rather than spaghettied throughout your application.

Comment: @Nick - good point. I was thinking "what if I decide to change the location of all of these images, then I'd have to update all of the rows in the database. If I'm using it all over in the views though...it'd probably be less work to update the rows.

Comment: @Nick: That's arguable. I'd personally rather change one place in code when I need to change the base folder than come up with a script to change all the appropriate strings in my database folder. But I would at least want to use a constant rather than scattering "~/content/images" all around my views.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, I would agree that is the way to go if you don't decide to go my route, however, it seems unnecessary to store part of the image path in the business logic and the other part in the database. It's a database concern only. Writing a script on the rare(hopefully) occasion that the folder changes is not complicated.

Comment: @Nick - would you store the absolute path like http:/ /www.example.com/content/images/etc.jpg or /content/images/etc.jpg. My fear is I don't want it to work in a dev environment and then break in a staging/production environment that is in a virtual directory.

Comment: @Dismissile, If you fear that I would use the absolute URL. Regardless of how you construct the path (absolute or not), I strongly believe it should it should all go in the database.

Comment: I would personally use the application-relative path unless you think that some day you're going to offload these images to a dedicated content server. As long as the images are expected to exist within your project, I'd prefer to allow ASP.NET to help you figure out what the "real" URL should be on the fly.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just do it!

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images" + Model.ImageUrl)" />
```

**UPDATE:**

As of ASP.NET MVC 4 it is valid to use the tilde URLs directly in HTML as the Razor View Engine will parse the URLs. Like this:

```
<img src="~/content/images/@Model.ImageUrl" />
```

Comment: Bah! I should've actually tried it before assuming it wouldn't work. I tried to do something like: @Url.Content("~/content/images/@Model.ImageUrl") before I typed out my question, and then I modified my question to be how I figured it would work :)

Comment: It takes a little while to get into Razor, but once you're there - There is no going back.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET MVC and are editing a Razor based view, there is no need for any `@using` at all to access `@Url.Action(..)`

Comment: I tried using it like this <img src="~/content/images/@Model.ImageUrl" /> in razor and MVC 4 and had no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can write extension method which combine your ImageUrl with configured path to content directory.

```
<img src="@Model.ImageUrl.ToRelative()" alt="@Model.ImageAlt" />
```

PS
Remember about alt tag. ;)