# Url.Content and reading ~ tilde in URL from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 with .aspx view engine. 
I have Maps.xml file:

```
    <imgurl>
        ../../Content/Img/BrandsLogo/samsung_logo.png
    </imgurl>
</map>
```

….

In the MapView.aspx I have:

```
<%: Url.Content( Model.ImgUrl ) %>
```

This works well, the image is displayed as it should.

The problem is:
I want to use the tilde in the xml file:

```
    <imgurl>
        ~/Content/Img/BrandsLogo/samsung_logo.png
    </imgurl>
```

But then the URL to the image is broken; somehow it adds Mobile/MapView in it. Which is the folder and .aspx file like this?

**/Mobile/MapView/~/Content/Img/BrandsLogo/samsung_logo.png**

When I use the ../../ in the xml file the URl is correct:
**/Content/Img/BrandsLogo/samsung_logo.png**

I have tried the solution form:
[Using Url.Content with semi-relative URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331777/using-url-content-with-semi-relative-url)

but then I get some extra spaces:
**/Content/Img/BrandsLogo%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20/samsung_logo.png**

How can I read tilde url `(~/Content/Img/BrandsLogo/samsung_logo.png)` from the xml file and use `Url.Content` method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the solution for which you provided the URL with a slight modification by using `Trim()` method:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Img/BrandsLogo" + Model.ImageUrl.Trim())" />
```

Comment: I just noticed where my extra spaces was coming from. I made them by having extra line in the xml file:  <imgurl>
            /motorola_logo.png
        </imgurl>

Comment: Yes, XML reads every single character you type so it's best to write it as dense as possible..