# Image doesn't show even when I can see it doing inspect in the browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have tried for more than two hours and I can not find an answer to this problem. I have this part of the code in a view strongly typed in MVC:

```
<td>
    @foreach (var TitleBook in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images"), "*.jpg"))
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(TitleBook);
        if (Convert.ToInt32(fileName.Substring(0,3)) == item.IdBook)
        {
            <img src="@TitleBook" alt="Alternate Text" height="100" width="100">
        }
    }
</td>
```

The name of the image file is created so the three first characters in the filename are numbers.

When I run the code, I get the alternate message for the image in the hmtl view. However, the path to this image is well read and I know it because I can obtain it by doing inspect in the browser and calling only the src part of  in another window which shows the image as expected (sorry for my English). The css is handled by the version of boostrap installed in VS2017. 
Could someone point to my error here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Url.Content with semi-relative URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331777/using-url-content-with-semi-relative-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `titleBook` is a full physical path. But `<img>` wants an URL.

Untested:

```
<img src="~/App_Data/Images/@fileName" alt="Alternate Text" height="100" width="100">
```

BTW: with `Directory.GetFiles(..., $"{item.IdBook:D3}*.jpg"))` you wouldn't need the foreach loop.

Comment: It doesn't give me a different result

Comment: Debug (or hover the link) and verify/repair it.  Or use "View Source" from your browser.  I'm indeed not sure if the `~` will be processed correctly. That's why: "untested".

Comment: Regarding your note:Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1001: Identifier expected

Source Error:


Line 55:             </td>
Line 56:             <td>
Line 57:                 @Directory.GetFiles(..., $"{item.IdBook:D3}*.jpg"))
Line 58:             </td>
Line 59:             <td>

Comment: Those `...` were of course not meant literally. Replace it with Mappath again.

Comment: Side note: You are doing way too much in your View. The image URL(s) should have been calculated by the Controller and put into a ViewModel.

Comment: Sorry for that: I did this: <td>
                @Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images"), $"{item.IdBook:D3}*.jpg"))
            </td> and instead of the image I got : System.String[]

Comment: Instead of a foreach you need  `GetFiles(...).FirstOrDefault()`